# restoring SQL text from logical plan

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing a customized listener in Spark that receives parsed logical plan. After analysis, I need to restore a subtree of the plan back to SQL. I'm wondering is there any function in Spark SQL that converts a logical plan to SQL text?

Comment: I know this is an old post but curious to know if you got the reply to this. Could you please let me know how you resolved this?